# How to hide an excel application and show the userforms?

Tags: excel, vba

How to hide an excel application and show the userforms ?when the workbook is opened? in such a way that when opening and closing of other excel workbooks do not affect the userforms opened

i have written the code to hide the workbook and it all runs out well but when opening and closing other workbooks the userforms quit.

Comment: You would need to use VB.NET instead for that.

Comment: The Workbook would need to be opened in a new instance of Excel. You would have to run a Code in an already opened Workbook which opens your desired Workbook as `Dim XLinst As New Excel.Application` like this `XLinst.Workbooks.Open "YourWorkbook.xlsm"`. The new instance will not be affected by changes to other instances of excel

Comment: thanks for the help i will try this out